# Android: Nothing happens on replacing fragment with another fragment

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-tabhost

First fragment contains list and when a user choose one of the list, another fragment will display but nothing happens. BTW first fragment is part of one of the tab on the Home.Home contains two tabs and First fragment is one of it which is the code i posted below.

```
public class Home_SpecialOffer extends Fragment {

    static ConnectivityManager cm;
    AlertDialog dialog2;
    AlertDialog.Builder build;

    ListView lvhomespecialoffer;
    private ProgressDialog dialog;

    @Nullable
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.home_specialoffer, container, false);

        cm = (ConnectivityManager) getActivity().getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);// checking
        build = new AlertDialog.Builder(getActivity()); // connectivity

        dialog = new ProgressDialog(getActivity());
        dialog.setIndeterminate(true);
        dialog.setCancelable(false);
        dialog.setMessage("Loading. Please wait...");

        // Create default options which will be used for every
        //  displayImage(...) call if no options will be passed to this method
        DisplayImageOptions defaultOptions = new DisplayImageOptions.Builder()
                .cacheInMemory(true)
                .cacheOnDisk(true)
                .build();
        ImageLoaderConfiguration config = new ImageLoaderConfiguration.Builder(getActivity())
                .defaultDisplayImageOptions(defaultOptions)
                .build();

        if (cm.getNetworkInfo(ConnectivityManager.TYPE_WIFI)// if connection is
                // there screen goes
                // to next screen
                // else shows
                // message
                .isConnectedOrConnecting()
                || cm.getNetworkInfo(ConnectivityManager.TYPE_MOBILE)
                .isConnectedOrConnecting()) {
            Log.e("cm value",
                    ""
                            + cm.getNetworkInfo(ConnectivityManager.TYPE_WIFI)
                            .isConnectedOrConnecting());

            ImageLoader.getInstance().init(config); // Do it on Application start

            lvhomespecialoffer = (ListView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.lvhomespecialoffer);

            new JSONTask().execute("this is my url");

        }
        else {

            build.setMessage("This application requires Internet connection. Would you connect to internet ?");
            build.setPositiveButton("Yes", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {

                @Override
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

                    startActivity(new Intent(Settings.ACTION_WIFI_SETTINGS));

                }
            });
            build.setNegativeButton("No", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {

                @Override
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {

                    getActivity().finish();
                }
            });
            dialog2 = build.create();
            dialog2.show();

        }

        return rootView;

    }

    public class JSONTask extends AsyncTask<String,String, List<ProductModel> > {

        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {
            super.onPreExecute();
            dialog.show();
        }

        @Override
        protected List<ProductModel> doInBackground(String... params) {
            HttpURLConnection connection = null;
            BufferedReader reader = null;

            try {
                URL url = new URL(params[0]);
                connection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
                connection.connect();
                InputStream stream = connection.getInputStream();
                reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(stream));
                StringBuffer buffer = new StringBuffer();
                String line ="";
                while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null){
                    buffer.append(line);
                }

                String finalJson = buffer.toString();

                JSONArray json = new JSONArray(finalJson);

                List<ProductModel> productModelList = new ArrayList<>();

                Gson gson = new Gson();
                for(int i=0; i<json.length(); i++) {
                    JSONObject finalObject = json.getJSONObject(i);
                    ProductModel productModel = gson.fromJson(finalObject.toString(), ProductModel.class);

                    productModelList.add(productModel);
                }
                return productModelList;

            } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (JSONException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } finally {
                if(connection != null) {
                    connection.disconnect();
                }
                try {
                    if(reader != null) {
                        reader.close();
                    }
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
            return  null;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(List<ProductModel> result) {
            super.onPostExecute(result);
            dialog.dismiss();
            ProductAdapter adapter = new ProductAdapter(getActivity(), R.layout.row, result);
            View footer = getActivity().getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.footer, null);
            lvhomespecialoffer.addFooterView(footer);
            lvhomespecialoffer.setAdapter(adapter);
            // TODO need to set data to the list



        }
    }

    public class ProductAdapter extends ArrayAdapter {

        private List<ProductModel> productModelList;
        private int resource;
        private LayoutInflater inflater;
        public ProductAdapter(Context context, int resource, List<ProductModel> objects) {
            super(context, resource, objects);
            productModelList = objects;
            this.resource = resource;
            inflater = (LayoutInflater) getActivity().getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        }

        @Override
        public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

            ViewHolder holder = null;

            if(convertView == null){
                holder = new ViewHolder();
                convertView = inflater.inflate(resource, null);
                holder.imgimage = (ImageView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.imgimage);
                holder.txtproduct = (TextView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.txtproduct);
                holder.txtprice = (TextView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.txtprice);
                holder.btnbuy = (Button)convertView.findViewById(R.id.btnbuy);

                convertView.setTag(holder);
            } else {
                holder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
            }

            final ProgressBar progressBar = (ProgressBar)convertView.findViewById(R.id.progressBar);

            // Then later, when you want to display image
            ImageLoader.getInstance().displayImage(productModelList.get(position).getImg_file(), holder.imgimage, new ImageLoadingListener() {
                @Override
                public void onLoadingStarted(String imageUri, View view) {
                    progressBar.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                }

                @Override
                public void onLoadingFailed(String imageUri, View view, FailReason failReason) {
                    progressBar.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                }

                @Override
                public void onLoadingComplete(String imageUri, View view, Bitmap loadedImage) {
                    progressBar.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                }

                @Override
                public void onLoadingCancelled(String imageUri, View view) {
                    progressBar.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                }
            });

            holder.txtproduct.setText(productModelList.get(position).getProduct_title());
            holder.txtprice.setText(("PHP ")+String.format("%.2f",(productModelList.get(position).getUnit_price())));

            holder.btnbuy.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {

//                    Toast.makeText(getActivity(),
//                           productModelList.get(position).getProduct_title()+" is not yet available!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

                    // Create new fragment and transaction
                    Fragment newFragment = new ProductDetails();
                    FragmentTransaction transaction = getFragmentManager().beginTransaction();

                    // Replace whatever is in the fragment_container view with this fragment,
                    // and add the transaction to the back stack
                    transaction.replace(R.id.specialoffer, newFragment);
                    transaction.addToBackStack(null);

                    // Commit the transaction
                    transaction.commit();

                }
            });


            return convertView;
        }

        class ViewHolder{
            private ImageView imgimage;
            private TextView txtproduct;
            private TextView txtprice;
            private Button btnbuy;

        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Is their is any error message on log?

Comment: no @ShahidNeermunda the only problem is it is not proceeding to ProductDetails which is the next fragment

Comment: @ShahidNeermunda and btw when i click the listview, nothing happens so it does not have an error

Answer (score 1):

Set your btnBuy button clickable in res/layout file.

```
<Button
 android:id="@+id/btnBuy"
 android:layout_width="match_parent"
 android:layout_height="wrap_content"
 android:clickable="true"/>
```

Comment: fragment still didnt change but when i attach toast, it is working

Comment: use the getSupportFragmentManager instead of getFragmentManager

Comment: What is R.id.specialoffer? Is it FrameLayout?

Comment: Just download sample from http://developer.android.com/training/basics/fragments/index.html and follow it.

Comment: linear and the framelayout is in the home and that home contains drawer and tab

Answer (score 0):

If you use the fragment in support package.you have to use `getSupportFragmentManager()`